# Optional Parameter for a Subject

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, subject

I have a subject in my Angular Service,

```
itemClicked: Subject<MenuTab | MenuLaunchTab, MenuItem>;
```

The problem is, I want to pass `MenuItem` **only** when I pass `MenuTab` as my first parameter, while pass **nothing** as my second parameter when the first parameter is `MenuLaunchTab`.

I want to replicate what we do for function arguments:

```
function(tab: MenuTab | MenuLaunchTab, item?: MenuItem)
```

Comment: Do you mind elaborating a bit, I don't really get it

Comment: did rxjs start allowing multiple type arguments to a subject recently? or is this some extension of the library?

Comment: `Subject` has only one type parameter: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.5.5/src/internal/Subject.ts#L28

Answer (score -1):

You need to combine both of types instead of union usage.

```js
itemClicked: Subject<MenuTab, MenuItem> & Subject<MenuLaunchTab>;
```

now `itemClicked` supports both `Subject<MenuTab, MenuItem>` and `Subject<MenuLaunchTab>` but neither `Subject<MenuTab>` nor `Subject<MenuLaunchTab, MenuItem>`.

A function should unite all possible types of its overrides.
Unfortunately, it means there's no other way than

```js
function(tab: MenuTab | MenuLaunchTab, item?: MenuItem)
```

What you can do is to detect types at the beginning and then split your flow.

```js
function(tab: MenuTab | MenuLaunchTab, item?: MenuItem) {
  // or other check that fits, because their definition is unclear.
  const menuLaunchTab: MenuLaunchTab | undefined = item ? undefined : tab;
  const menuTab: MenuTab | undefined = item ? tab : undefined;
  if (menuTab) {
    handlerOfmenuTab(menuTab, item);
  } else if (menuLaunchTab) {
    handlerOfmenuLaunchTab(menuLaunchTab);
  }

}
```

Comment: Providing an explanation of code is always welcome, and generally results in more upvotes and fewer downvotes than a line of code with no explanation.